# possible to implement abstract base function with property in derived contract?

Tags: solidity, inheritance, abstract

Is there any way to have an abstract base contract with an abstract function which gets implemented in a derived contract by a property (and not a function)?

e.g. the following attempts failed:

```
contract Base {
    //function f() public returns (uint256);
    function f() external view returns (uint256); // also not working
}

contract Derived is Base {
    uint256 public f;
}
```

In all cases `Derived` is still abstract because it does not implement `f` from the `Base` contract although the ABI is identical. A typical scenario is e.g. a tokens which implements the ERC20 interface an `totalSupply` might just be implemented with a property and not a getter and a property (in most simple cases that would suffice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Known issue

This is a known problem, with an open issue in the solidity bug tracker.

Please see: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3514